# Soap Request Information Needed VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, soap

We are using an API from a third party company, they want us to send the SOAP request.  I asked a co-worker to help with this and we got as far as the XML but can't figure out how to get the soap request the way they want it.  Here is our code so far.

```vb
Public Sub WriteToRoadNet()
        Dim tws As New RoadNetWebServices.TransportationWebService With {
            .Url = WebServiceURL
        }

        Dim Recipient As New RoadNetWebServices.ActiveAlertRecipient
        With Recipient
            If Me.Pkey > 0 Then .pKey = Me.Pkey Else .pKey = Nothing

            If Not Me.IsEmail Then
                .activeAlertMethod = RoadNetWebServices.ActiveAlertMethod.nsmText
                If Me.PreDelivery Then
                    .minutesBeforeDelivery = 15
                Else
                    .minutesBeforeDelivery = 0
                End If
                .delivered = False
                .initialETA = False
                .updatedETA = False
            Else
                .activeAlertMethod = RoadNetWebServices.ActiveAlertMethod.nsmEmail
                .minutesBeforeDelivery = 0
                .delivered = Me.Delivered
                .initialETA = Me.InitialETA
                .updatedETA = Me.UpdatedETA
            End If

            .recipientType = Me.RecipientType
            .locationIdentity = New RoadNetWebServices.LocationIdentity
            With .locationIdentity
                .locationID = LocationID 'RID
                .locationType = "SIT"
                .regionID = "CE"
            End With
            .recipients = Me.Recipient
        End With
        Dim Recipients() As RoadNetWebServices.ActiveAlertRecipient = {Recipient}

        '**********************************************************
        Dim serxml As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(tws.SaveActiveAlertRecipients(Recipients).GetType())
        Dim ms = New System.IO.MemoryStream()
        serxml.Serialize(ms, tws.SaveActiveAlertRecipients(Recipients))
        Dim xml As String = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray())
        '**********************************************************  

        Try
            Recipients = tws.SaveActiveAlertRecipients(Recipients)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Logger.Log(ex)
            Environment.Exit(-1)
        End Try

        tws = Nothing
        Recipient = Nothing
        Recipients = Nothing
    End Sub
```

The XML output

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfActiveAlertRecipient xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ActiveAlertRecipient>
        <pKey xmlns="http://www.roadnet.com/RTS/TransportationSuite/TransportationWebService">0</pKey>
        <locationIdentity xmlns="http://www.roadnet.com/RTS/TransportationSuite/TransportationWebService">
            <regionID>CE</regionID>
            <locationType>SIT</locationType>
            <locationID>359862</locationID>
        </locationIdentity>
        <recipientType xmlns="http://www.roadnet.com/RTS/TransportationSuite/TransportationWebService">002</recipientType>
        <activeAlertMethod xmlns="http://www.roadnet.com/RTS/TransportationSuite/TransportationWebService">nsmText</activeAlertMethod>
        <recipients xmlns="http://www.roadnet.com/RTS/TransportationSuite/TransportationWebService">4842562961</recipients>
        <initialETA xmlns="http://www.roadnet.com/RTS/TransportationSuite/TransportationWebService">false</initialETA>
        <updatedETA xmlns="http://www.roadnet.com/RTS/TransportationSuite/TransportationWebService">false</updatedETA>
        <arrived xmlns="http://www.roadnet.com/RTS/TransportationSuite/TransportationWebService">false</arrived>
        <delivered xmlns="http://www.roadnet.com/RTS/TransportationSuite/TransportationWebService">false</delivered>
        <missedTimeWindow xmlns="http://www.roadnet.com/RTS/TransportationSuite/TransportationWebService">false</missedTimeWindow>
        <minutesBeforeDelivery xmlns="http://www.roadnet.com/RTS/TransportationSuite/TransportationWebService">0</minutesBeforeDelivery>
        <isDelete xmlns="http://www.roadnet.com/RTS/TransportationSuite/TransportationWebService">false</isDelete>
    </ActiveAlertRecipient>
</ArrayOfActiveAlertRecipient>
```

A sample of what the third part company wants.

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<SaveRoute xmlns="http://www.roadnet.com/RTS/TransportationSuite/TransportationWebService">
<route>
    <routeIdentity>
        <regionID>STLOUIS</regionID>
        <routeDate>2014-01-31</routeDate>
        <routeID>TEST</routeID>
    </routeIdentity>
    <description>Hazelwood</description>
    <internalRouteID>863837</internalRouteID>
    <assigned>true</assigned>
    <outOfSequence>false</outOfSequence>
    <seal/>
    <plannedDistance>185.38</plannedDistance>
    <projectedDistance>185.38</projectedDistance>
    <actualDistance>0</actualDistance>
    <plannedStart>2014-01-31T11:00:00</plannedStart>
    <plannedOriginDeparture>2014-01-31T11:20:00</plannedOriginDeparture>
    <plannedDestinationArrival>2014-01-31T22:08:42</plannedDestinationArrival>
    <plannedComplete>2014-01-31T22:28:42</plannedComplete>
    <projectedOriginDeparture>2014-01-31T11:20:00</projectedOriginDeparture>
    <projectedDestinationArrival>2014-01-31T22:08:42</projectedDestinationArrival>
    <projectedComplete>2014-01-31T22:28:42</projectedComplete>
    <routeStartTimeQuality>dqtUnknown</routeStartTimeQuality>
    <originDepartTimeQuality>dqtUnknown</originDepartTimeQuality>
    <destinationArrivalTimeQuality>dqtUnknown</destinationArrivalTimeQuality>
    <routeCompleteTimeQuality>dqtUnknown</routeCompleteTimeQuality>
    <plannedCost>418</plannedCost>
    <actualCost>0</actualCost>
    <dispatcherID/>
    <group/>
    <scenario>DELIVERY</scenario>
    <wirelessLoaded>true</wirelessLoaded>
    <wirelessProvider>wpCustom</wirelessProvider>
    <inProgress>false</inProgress>
    <complete>false</complete>
    <gpsUnitID/>
    <lastInboundMessageId>0</lastInboundMessageId>
    <numberOfStops>XXX</numberOfStops>
    <numberOfStopsDelivered>0</numberOfStopsDelivered>
    <numberOfStopsCancelled>0</numberOfStopsCancelled>
    <positionText/>
    <positionLatitude>XXX </positionLatitude>
    <positionLongitude>XXXX</positionLongitude>
    <delayMinutes>0</delayMinutes>
    <delayType/>
    <postDelayMinutes>0</postDelayMinutes>
    <postDelayType/>
    <status/>
    <routeType/>
    <lastStopIsDestination>false</lastStopIsDestination>
    <origin>
        <regionID>STLOUIS</regionID>
        <locationType>DPT</locationType>
        <locationID>631</locationID>
    </origin>
    <destination>
        <regionID>STLOUIS</regionID>
        <locationType>DPT</locationType>
        <locationID>631</locationID>
    </destination>
    <originTimeZone>tmzCentralTimeUSCanada</originTimeZone>
    <destinationTimeZone>tmzCentralTimeUSCanada</destinationTimeZone>
    <userDefinedField1>3145024000</userDefinedField1>
    <userDefinedField2/>
    <userDefinedField3/>
    <color>16711680</color>
    <isDeliveryRoute>true</isDeliveryRoute>
    <helper>rhtNonHelper</helper>
    <driver1Name>XXX</driver1Name>
    <driver2Name/>
    <preRouteSurveyIdentity xsi:nil="true"/>
    <postRouteSurveyIdentity xsi:nil="true"/>
    <reportedDistance>-1</reportedDistance>
    <reportedDistanceNote/>
    <stops>
        <stopIdentity>
            <regionID>STLOUIS</regionID>
            <routeDate>2014-01-31</routeDate>
            <routeID>TEST</routeID>
            <internalStopID>1</internalStopID>
        </stopIdentity>
        <stopIndex>0</stopIndex>
        <plannedSequenceNum>1</plannedSequenceNum>
        <actualSequenceNum>1</actualSequenceNum>
        <stopType>stpStop</stopType>
        <locationIdentity>
            <regionID>STLOUIS</regionID>
            <locationType>SIT</locationType>
            <locationID>2073379-003</locationID>
        </locationIdentity>
        <latitude>38781094</latitude>
        <longitude>-90482698</longitude>
        <buildingDeliverySequence>0</buildingDeliverySequence>
        <consignee/>
        <shipper/>
        <deliveryRadius>0.05</deliveryRadius>
        <plannedArrival>2014-01-31T11:43:09</plannedArrival>
        <projectedArrival>2014-01-31T11:43:09</projectedArrival>
        <arrivalTimeQuality>dqtUnknown</arrivalTimeQuality>
        <departureTimeQuality>dqtUnknown</departureTimeQuality>
        <plannedDeparture>2014-01-31T12:04:45</plannedDeparture>
        <projectedDeparture>2014-01-31T12:04:45</projectedDeparture>
        <cancelled>false</cancelled>
        <plannedDistance>18.23</plannedDistance>
        <projectedDistance>18.23</projectedDistance>
        <actualDistance>0</actualDistance>
        <openTime>2014-01-31T10:00:00</openTime>
        <closeTime>2014-02-01T05:00:00</closeTime>
        <tw1OpenTime>2014-01-31T10:00:00</tw1OpenTime>
        <tw1CloseTime>2014-01-31T12:00:00</tw1CloseTime>
        <tw2OpenTime>2014-01-31T22:00:00</tw2OpenTime>
        <tw2CloseTime>2014-02-01T05:00:00</tw2CloseTime>
        <delayType/>
        <delayMinutes>0</delayMinutes>
        <seal/>
        <userDefinedField1/>
        <userDefinedField2/>
        <userDefinedField3/>
        <locationUserDefinedField1/>
        <locationUserDefinedField2></locationUserDefinedField2>
        <locationUserDefinedField3></locationUserDefinedField3>
        <timeZone>tmzEasternTimeUSCanada</timeZone>
        <instructions></instructions>
        <redeliveryID>0</redeliveryID>
        <cancelCode/>
        <undeliverableCode/>
        <undeliverable>false</undeliverable>
        <additionalServiceTime>0</additionalServiceTime>
        <quantities xsi:nil="true"/>
        <reasonCodes xsi:nil="true"/>
        <locationName></locationName>
        <address>
            <line1></line1>
            <line2/>
            <crossStreet/>
            <region1>Saint Charles</region1>
            <region2>SaintCharles</region2>
            <region3>MO</region3>
            <postalCode>633012844</postalCode>
            <country>US</country>
        </address>
        <phoneNumber></phoneNumber>
        <driver1Name></driver1Name>
        <driver2Name/>
        <routeComplete>false</routeComplete>
        <routeInProgress>false</routeInProgress>
        <plannedDeliveryCost>40</plannedDeliveryCost>
        <actualDeliveryCost>0</actualDeliveryCost>
        <surveyIdentity xsi:nil="true"/>
        <removeFlag>false</removeFlag>
    </stops>
</route>
<placementOptions>
<placementType>sptNone</placementType>
<stopIdentity xsi:nil="true"/>
</placementOptions>
<timeZoneOptions>
<embeddedInTimestamp>false</embeddedInTimestamp>
<optionType>tzoGMT</optionType>
<timeZone>tmzNone</timeZone>
</timeZoneOptions>
</SaveRoute>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Build your `route` node (and respective child nodes) by creating an XElement and setting its respective values. Then just preappend the SOAP information as a String to the result of ToString on your `route` node.

Comment: Just need the tweak to get the SOAP xml instead of just the plain XML, I don't understand your answer.

Comment: I am assuming that you have all of the values found in the `route` node that the 3rd party vendor is requiring, correct?

Comment: The xml sample is the result my code produced, the second sample is not what we are aming for but is a sample of the style of soap request output they want.  I shared the two samples so you could see the difference and help me adjust my code to produce the correctly styled soap XML output.